# User Account Creation and Facebook Connect

Tags: coldfusion, facebook

I'm wanting to expand on my user account creation and perhaps implement Facebook Connect... however, I'm not quite understanding just how far Facebook Connect goes. I mean, when singing into Facebook, there's no way that you're allowed to then take the information from a Facebook account and store it into your own database, right?

What is the suggested workflow when incorporating Facebook with your account creation and login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How far does it go? Well fact, yes, once you get explicit authorisation (permission) for certain objects from the FB user then you can do with them what you wish - becuase the user has trusted you with their info. If you abuse that info then FB will get complaints and will take action against your application, which must be registered with them.

I recommend the [offical FB Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) - it can do everything you'd expect and has some great examples. It will also be kept up to date by Facebook (their developer tools change weekly - [see blog here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/)) which may not be the case with CF APIs ported to other languages.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Ciaran. I'm just trying to clear up what you're allowed to do with the information that you are able to access when using the Facebook API. My original thoughts were to sign in with Facebook and use that information to create an account in my application.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the subject of your request. If you are interested in Facebook integration with ColdFusion, you should take a look at the excellent facebook sdk here: http://facebooksdk.riaforge.org/
(note: 9.0.1 compatibility)